# How to use AuthorizeView tag with custom authentication logic in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a custom authentication system in Blazor server app, with custom database and some logic.

I'd like to benefit from built-in AuthorizeView tag in razor. But I don't know how to use it without AspNetCore.Identity.

Now I have a global property bool IsAuthorized to check if user logged in.
On top of mind I am thinking that maybe I could bind IsAuthorized property to AuthorizeView tags Authorize and NotAuthorized.

I read through AuthorizeView reference, but couldn't find which property controls it's state.

Is it possible to use AuthorizeView in custom authentication logic, without built-in "Identity"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create your own AuthenticationStateProvider and override the GetAuthenticationStateAsync method. I don't know the logic behind your auth, but maybe you can create a ClaimsIdentity and ClaimsPrincipal from your auth logic in that method and set the authenticationstate. To understand better how it works here is an example for creating your own AuthenticationStateProvider and getting the autstate from a token in wasm:

https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/

Comment: Thanks. I did it in a different way, but your answer gave me a starting point.