# Blazor Custom Authorize Attribure or Custom RouteView for authentication - Route Protection

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, authorize-attribute, asp.net-blazor

I am developing a blazor **web assembly** app, I am authenticating users using **custom RouteView**.

I simply check if a component has AuthorizeAttribute and then **call my AccountService** to check if a user is logged in or not.

```
public class AuthRouteView : RouteView
    {
        [Inject]
        public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        public IAccountService AccountService { get; set; }

        protected override void Render(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            var authorize = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(RouteData.PageType, typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)) != null;
            var allowAnonymous = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(RouteData.PageType, typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute)) != null;

            var loggedIn = AccountService.isLoggedIn();

            if (authorize && !loggedIn && !allowAnonymous)
            {
                var returnUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).PathAndQuery);
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?returnUrl={returnUrl}");
            }
            else
            {
                base.Render(builder);
            }
        }
    }
```

It's all working fine, Now what I want to do is **check for a role for some components**, I was thinking of writing a **custom Authorize attribute**, **moved** all the logic to it from **AuthRouteView**, and then **passing a role** to it and that **attribute will then check** if the user has a role, **but the attribute is not getting invoked**.

In my **AuthRouteView**, I am **unable** to get the **parameter I passed** to the attribute so I'll check that here.

here is my custom attribute.

```
public class Authorize : Attribute, IAuthorizeData
{
    private string role;

    public Authorize(string role = "")
    {
      this.role = role;
    }
}
```

I have checked in **Attribute** and **IAuthorizeData** they both don't contain any **protected** method for me to **override**.

I inherited it from **IAuthorizeData** because the **built-in Authorize attribute** is also inherited from it.

I am confused about two things here?

1. Am I following the right way (using AuthRouteView) to Authenticate or Authorize the User. (Authorization is where I am stuck right now). because I don't find any example for custom authentication and authorization.
2. Can we write custom attributes that get invoked before the component initialize?

Comment: "because I don't find any example for custom authentication and authorization"
See if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466919/how-to-use-authorizeview-tag-with-custom-authentication-logic-in-blazor/66496048#66496048

Comment: Why are you writing custom Authorization components when it looks like what you want is a custom AuthenticationStateProvider that uses your Account Service?  You can then use all the standard Authorize stuff provided by Blazor?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the asker is not responding to any comments

Comment: Okay, I understood., writing AuthenticationStateProvider will solve the problem. Thanks